# Google Sheets string styling with a simple string concat

Tags: google-sheets

This is probably a very noob question but here goes:

```
="Book title:    " & A6 & yesNo!C3
```

This outputs (for example):

> Book title:     The Golden Egg Yes

How can I add styling in the formula so the output always reads like this (ie the cell A6 in bold):

> Book title:     **The Golden Egg** Yes

Comment: For now, come on, be satisfied! It can be done with just a formula, without a script ... I'm trying to simplify everything and then I'll give you the answer and a link

Answer (score 1):

[image: concatenate with mixed formatting]

The idea is to use extremely high Unicode code, like 119808 for a bold A ... but there is still work to be done and the result is not very satisfying. An apps script solution is definitely better than the actual formula.

This is a [link to the test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15bNTltJ4VydXcrHtw7dLUaB-E5zMuxpQdU7WU1J9guI/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: wowza! That is incredibly more complex that i ever imagined :D thank you!